# link tag calling js function don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, tags

I have a static site with classic menu like: home, services, contact etc links.
**What I'm trying to do is reducing the site's size.**
So, instead of using multiple pages for links (like home.html, services.html) I'm trying to keep only one page and then (when clicking occurs) dynamically change content.

html code (sample):

```
<a href="javascript:this.location.reload()" onClick="ContactClick();">contact</a>
<h1>old text</h1>
```

js code:

```
function ContactClick() {
    $('h1').html('new text to change, but it doesnt work, yay!');   
}
```

Something funny happens. If I click on the link, 'old text' becomes indeed 'new text', BUT ONLY FOR 1 SECOND! And then, it changes right back to 'old text'!

I have tryied calling like this: `<a href="javascript:ContactClick();">` and it works just fine, but still I need to refresh the page when click event occurs (I have some color changing stuff on site, lol).

1. Is there another way to reduce site's size, or my idea is just fine? 
   **OR**
2. Is there a solve including refreshing the site and calling the js junction from link?

Comment: If you reload the page, well, you reload the page. Everything about the page prior to the reload is completely thrown out by the browser.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you shouldn't be reloading the page in your `href`.

Comment: I get it now, stupid me. of course the 'old text' is changing in 'new text', but right afterwards page refreshes turning again in 'old text', just like Pointy said. lanzz, why should I not refreshing in href? What if I'm refreshing in js function, is that good practice? Codes working now, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reduce the site's size. Static pages that contain only text are small and load in a fraction of a second even at the first time. After that, they will be in cache and load instantly.

On the other hand, if you put all the text in one page, plus add some javascript code, the result is not smaller but *bigger* than the static pages.

Further, you should remember that javascript does not always work. For example, many people disable javascript for security reasons or to avoid irritating advertisements. Therefore, navigation should never be dependent on javascript. At the very least, you should have noscript part that works with static pages in case javascript is disabled. (But this will make the page even bigger.)

Comment: 1. You are right. Just checked the index.html size. Is 2 kb. 2. However, using javascript, i dont think the result is bigger. just checked the my.js size. I'ts 950 bytes. 3. You are not right. Javascript is 'the' language of internet. Sincerely, I dont think that a disabled-javascript-user will enter on my webpage. Thanks!

Comment: How can the javascript page not be bigger if it contains all the same text PLUS the javascript code? Further, putting everything in one page forces the user to load everything even if they only want to see one page.

Comment: If I know correctly, a static page does not contain only the content text to be changed, contains the whole text from !doctype to </html>. That is, a whole lot of text than the text itself. And even if I am wrong, and you are right, all sites have javascript files. Adding a few lines in that javascript file would be weighting in order of... bytes? 100 words = 100 bytes bigger? I dont think this will be so important.

Comment: *100 chars, not words, sorry.

Comment: Problem solved. Apparently working with static different files was best. 

Thank you guys.

The entire site has a total size of 725 KB. Is that good, if it's a simple site with no pictures?

Comment: @SantaDanDumitru: you think a disabled-JavaScript-user will enter your page? How about a blind user? What about a search engine crawler? They don't or can't use JavaScript, and for blind people, what you do makes the page impossible to navigate, and for web crawlers, it means none of your other pages will be indexed—hence, no one will find your site. Further, it'll make your site a lot harder for *you* to maintain, and it means e.g. users can't link to specific pages, because there's only one page with no ability to load up to a different subsection automatically! Static pages are best here.